# Media Center Style app

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, user-interface

I was wondering how I can make a GUI that looks like Media Center, so like this:
[image]

I don't know if it can be done with simple c# .net or if I have to use WPF or something. (The app needs to be written in C# style)

I found a couple of tutorials for WPF but nothing I can use to create such an nice looking GUI.

Hope somebody knows some good tutorial / sample code so I can begin my "home project"

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that with WPF. I cant say I have seen such a WPF app, but Silverlight is the same thing and I see stuff like that in Silverlight all the time.  You are going to need some experience with WPF and GUI programming, I have this book and I find its great: 3D Game Development with Microsoft Silverlight 3: Beginner's Guide

Comment: Ok and do you have a good tutorial with silverlight? Because the most of the tutorials I find are so basic and not what I'm looking for... Thanks anyway for your answer!

Comment: Looks like you need a menu that has similar effects to the Mac OS Launcher, try this: http://wpfdock.codeplex.com/

Comment: I've watched the source code but what a BUNCH of code for just that menu... :S I have to say I never worked with WPF before so it is abra cadabra for me right now :P

Comment: the tutorials will be basic because that's what tutorials are.  simple, to the point programs that do one or only a couple things, so that you understand how to do *that thing*.  Something like media center has *hundreds* of people involved, and has taken *years* to look like that.

Comment: Yes, I agree with John.  What you are asking sound like you woke up today and thought you could just write a dashboard for your TV that would have things specific for you.  Its not that easy.  Millions of dollars have gone into creating that good looking UI, to take on a project to copy it would be over your head in man power and/or time.

Comment: BTW, some Linux based copies do exist.

Answer (score 3):

You *could* do it with *anything*, but using WPF or silverlight would make it easier to do the animation/transitions and things.

I'd suggest looking at Expression Blend and the tutorials for that, like those at http://www.microsoft.com/design/toolbox

Comment: Ok, so I see people voting this up, but the problem with this statement is that is does no more good than telling him to use Visual Studio.  Expression Blend can do tons of "stuff" but without direction it can do nothing like what the question author is looking for.

Comment: The question was very vague, and I suggested Blend and those tutorials (which he asked for) because the blend examples show things like that.  Any question of the form "can i do X with simple c# .net" will generally get downvoted instantly as its not a very specific question.

Comment: By that explanation you are correct, and I dont really fault you for giving that suggestion.  I guess my rub was more with the people who voted your answer up as it didnt really add value... it more or less proved to be the reason why this type of question gets a down vote.